# How can a URL from my website be hidden?

Tags: web-server, dmz, websphere

I have my site which URL is *like* this: `https://test.my.webpage.example`

And I need to block a URL similar to: `https://test.my.webpage.example/weblogic/someApp/someService`

This is for a application in Java, over a WebSphere, that must communicate to a WebLogic. The webserver is behind a firewall on the DMZ. The appserver is on the GRN, as well as the server that has the weblogic.

When any person hit that URL, the expectation is to receive a default error page.

Comment: What kind of webserver?

Comment: IHS - With Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the WebSphere WebServer Plug-in, you can stop it from being proxied which should result in a webserver 404:

```
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI ^/+weblogic/+someApp/+someService$ skipwas=1
```

Otherwise, if you use mod_proxy, one simple way to return a 404 is with mod_rewrite, in the virtual host or base server config handling the hostname:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/+weblogic/+someApp/+someService - [R=404]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally did it with a change on httpd.conf, something like:

```
LoadModule weblogic_module /apps/web-apps/cncboltestenv2/cncboltestenv2_Runtime/testenv2_someapp/conf/lib/mod_wl.so

<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
        <Location /weblogic/instancia/>
                SecureProxy ON
                WebLogicCluster server01u:80443,server02u:80443
                WLSSLWallet /apps/web-apps/cncboltestenv2/cncboltestenv2_Runtime/testenv2_someapp/keys/Wallet
                DynamicServerList OFF
                pathtrim /weblogic
                SetHandler weblogic-handler
        </Location>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to block access to a URL.

[Sample 301 redirect Websphere](https://www.strongback.us/2010/07/redirecting-your-ihs-root-context-to-your-websphere-app-server-app)

If you use .htaccess to block the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (^|/)weblogic/someApp/someService(/|$) - [F]
```

[.htaccess sample](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216363167-How-do-I-deny-access-to-my-site-with-an-htaccess-file-)

Comment: Not for content that's proxied and doesn't hit the filesystem.